# нагрузка php socket

Tags: php, сокет

Добрый вечер. 
Новичок в php, решил использовать socket, но вот ни как не могу понять какую нагрузку создает открытый socket на сервере в ожидании соединения ? или сколько тратит машинных ресурсов ?

Comment: Хорроший вопрос. Сокеты в PHP редко используют (так было по крайней мере до появления поддержки сокетов в JS). Поидее там просто бесконечный цикл while - тоже подожду что ответят. Но проверить можно средствами аналитики ресурсов windows/linux